# Network UNCLAIMED Kali Linux 2.0

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I just installed Kali Linux on my Computer and noticed my WIFI isn't working. I have Windows 10 installed to and no Problems there. 
Here is some Information:

```
root@Kali:~# sudo lshw -c network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:e0800000-e080ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: e8:6a:64:62:b9:85
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp aui bnc mii fibre 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.178.37 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:31 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:e0704000-e0704fff memory:e0700000-e0703fff
```

And from a Script I found while trying to solve the Problem:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 12 Aug 2019 19:59 CEST +0200

Booted last: 12 Aug 2019 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:    2019.3
Codename:   kali-rolling

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.19.0-kali5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.37-6kali1 (2019-07-22) x86_64 unknown unknown GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet

##### desktop ###########################

GNOME

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:c024]
    Kernel modules: wl

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:38a8]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:c024 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 5986:210f Acer, Inc EasyCamera
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:0a4d Logitech, Inc. G430 Surround Sound Gaming Headset
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1ea7:1006 SHARKOON Technologies GmbH Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

'pccardctl' is not installed (package "pcmciautils").

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

'mokutil' is not installed (package "mokutil").

##### lsmod #############################

ath9k                 135168  0
ath9k_common           20480  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              483328  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    36864  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              815104  1 ath9k
wl                   6463488  0
ideapad_laptop         40960  0
cfg80211              761856  5 wl,ath9k_common,ath9k,ath,mac80211
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
rfkill                 28672  6 bluetooth,ideapad_laptop,cfg80211
wmi_bmof               16384  0
wmi                    28672  2 wmi_bmof,ideapad_laptop
video                  45056  1 ideapad_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.178.37/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 861433sec preferred_lft 861433sec
    inet6 2003:e8:573c:b400:2d48:1fc:5fec:9ad0/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 6739sec preferred_lft 1275sec
    inet6 2003:e8:573c:b400:<IP6 'eth0' [IF1]>/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 6739sec preferred_lft 1275sec
    inet6 fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF1]>/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.178.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100 
192.168.178.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.37 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[644 root '/etc/resolv.conf']
search fritz.box
nameserver fd00::9a9b:cbff:feaa:7b9
nameserver 192.168.178.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       723     1  0 19:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:02:00.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       eth0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       e8a013f2-3556-4a4f-9b53-c76d0b3c1ad7
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.178.37/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.178.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.178.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.178.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.178.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          fritz.box
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.178.255
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dad_wait_time = 0
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 864000
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        dhcp_rebinding_time = 756000
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        dhcp_renewal_time = 432000
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        domain_name = fritz.box
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1566494227
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       ip_address = 192.168.178.37
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       network_number = 192.168.178.0
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       next_server = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       ntp_servers = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[32]:                       routers = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[33]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2003:e8:573c:b400:2d48:1fc:5fec:9ad0/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         2003:e8:573c:b400:<IP6 'eth0' [IF1]>/64
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF1]>/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::9a9b:cbff:feaa:7b9
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 2003:e8:573c:b400::/56, nh = fe80::9a9b:cbff:feaa:7b9, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 2003:e8:573c:b400::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = fe80::9a9b:cbff:feaa:7b9, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[5]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.DNS[1]:                             fd00::9a9b:cbff:feaa:7b9
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        dad_wait_time = 0
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_client_id = 0:4:dd:43:a9:68:a5:69:fa:6b:80:9a:c9:67:8d:19:6:5
DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = fd00::9a9b:cbff:feaa:7b9
DHCP6.OPTION[4]:                        dhcp6_server_id = 0:3:0:1:98:9b:cb:aa:7:b9
DHCP6.OPTION[5]:                        dhcp6_unknown_86 = 20:3:0:e8:57:3c:b4:0:9a:9b:cb:ff:fe:aa:7:b9
DHCP6.OPTION[6]:                        requested_dhcp6_client_id = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[7]:                        requested_dhcp6_domain_search = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[8]:                        requested_dhcp6_name_servers = 1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   e8a013f2-3556-4a4f-9b53-c76d0b3c1ad7 | Wired connection 1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Berlin (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[ath9k]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.19.0-kali5-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
depends:        mac80211,ath9k_hw,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath9k
vermagic:       4.19.0-kali5-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           led_active_high:Invert LED polarity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)
parm:           use_chanctx:Enable channel context for concurrency (int)
parm:           use_msi:Use MSI instead of INTx if possible (int)

[ath9k_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.19.0-kali5-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless 802.11n LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
depends:        cfg80211,ath9k_hw,ath
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath9k_common
vermagic:       4.19.0-kali5-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions 

[ath9k_hw]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.19.0-kali5-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
depends:        ath
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath9k_hw
vermagic:       4.19.0-kali5-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions 

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.19.0-kali5-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath
vermagic:       4.19.0-kali5-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.19.0-kali5-amd64/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       4.19.0-kali5-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.19.0-kali5-amd64/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           wl
vermagic:       4.19.0-kali5-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.19.0-kali5-amd64/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
depends:        rfkill
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.19.0-kali5-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath9k]
blink: 0
bt_ant_diversity: 0
btcoex_enable: 0
led_active_high: -1
nohwcrypt: 1
ps_enable: 0
use_chanctx: 0
use_msi: 0

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

ath9k

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf]
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k_htc.conf]
options ath9k_htc use_dev_fw=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-libnfc.conf]
blacklist nfc
blacklist pn533

[/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-dkms.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist b44
blacklist bcma
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist ssb

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/libhackrf0.conf]
blacklist hackrf

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   17.952546] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/raven_gpu_info.bin
[   17.999166] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/raven_asd.bin
[   18.054085] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/raven_pfp.bin
[   18.055173] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/raven_me.bin
[   18.055515] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/raven_ce.bin
[   18.065112] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/raven_rlc.bin
[   18.094674] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/raven_mec.bin
[   18.124183] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/raven_mec2.bin
[   18.329159] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/raven_sdma.bin
[   18.331269] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/raven_vcn.bin
[   18.331275] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.9 DEC: 1 VEP: 0 Revision: 28
[   28.453542] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   28.573324] r8169 0000:02:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtl_nic/rtl8168g-3.fw
[   28.676982] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   28.677080] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: Link is Down
[   30.264938] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control off
[   30.264950] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Script Source: made by ardvark71
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/elementary-os-112/wifi-device-marked-unclaimed-in-dell-inspiron-3521-a-4175603973/

I really hope you can help me.

LG Luca

Comment: The script source is actually the Ubuntu forums, if I'm not mistaken. Other than the script which is useful for troubleshooting nothing else in that link is applicable to your case, totally different hardware. Try disabling Secure Boot before anything else.

Comment: Yeah I know that, secure boot is disabled. If was to activate it, Kali wouldn't even start.